# Confused about filling ComboBox with years

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a windows project and I have a years ComboBox that should contain years from 1910 to present .This my code for this

```
  comboboxYears.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1910, DateTime.Now.Year).ToList();
```

But the range is not between 1910 and present year. Instead its between 1910 and 3924. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [Enumerable.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28VS.90%29.aspx) expects the second parameter to be a `count`, not an `end`. The current year is 2015, so its populating it with 1910+2015 number of items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *second* parameter in [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28VS.90%29.aspx) is the ***number of integers to generate***, not the inclusive upper bound of the range. Here is the signature of this method:

```
Range(int start, int count)
```

So, you just need to pass either `last - start` or `last - start + 1` as a second paremeter depending on if you want to see the last integer in the sequence. (Thanks to [@juharr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302918/juharr) for comment)
 So, change your code as:

```
comboboxYears.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1910, DateTime.Now.Year - 1910 + 1).ToList();
```

Comment: Actually that should be `DateTime.Now.Year - 1910 + 1` assuming the OP wants the current year in the drop down.